# humans.txt returns a content-type of text/html, but the content is actually actually text/plain

Tags: bug

Simplified `curl` output:

```
$ curl -i https://stackoverflow.com/humans.txt
HTTP/2 200
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 03 Jan 2022 15:36:25 GMT

There's a bunch of humans behind Stack Overflow and the network of Stack Exchange sites. If you'd like to join us check out https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here
```

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/humans.txt` doesn't look like plaintext to me when I open that in a browser. It is wrapped in HTML.

Comment: @Tom that is just the browser doing its magic. The HTTP response body itself has no markup.

Comment: While it probably _doesn't_ break anything, this is still a bug. It broke in mid-2019 when we did some code refactoring to get rid of a complicated piece of code that was only being used for this specific file. Before that, it did correctly return text/plain as the content-type. And it's worth noting that the robots.txt file does return text/plain as the content-type.

Comment: @animuson: Shouldn't it get a `status-*` tag (e.g. [\[status-review\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-review))? Or is it a duplicate?